# Item click listener not working on a Auto Scrolling Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scroll, android-adapter

I am using the code below to auto scroll my recycler view.

```
private final Runnable SCROLLING_RUNNABLE = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mRecyclerView_news.smoothScrollBy(pixelsToMove, 0);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, duration);
    }
};

private void scrollRV(){
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

    mRecyclerView_news.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);           
    mRecyclerView_news.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(MainActivity.this, newsList, this);
    mRecyclerView_news.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 500);
}
```

I am also implementing a Click listener, but when the Recyclerview is scrolling, none of the item is being clicked. The click listener works fine when the recyclerview is not scrolling.

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Where do you call `scrollRV` method?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was caused by me having a recycler view and a scroll view. As they're both vertical scrolls, it was affecting my OnCLickListener. Either a nested scroll view or just taking the scroll view out altogether worked for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: I only have one recyclerview. There's no scroll view attached.

Answer (score 0):

#### I had a similar problem and I fixed by this way

**Write these interface and class in your activity file**

```
interface ClickListener {
    fun onClick(view: View?, position: Int)
    fun onLongClick(view: View?, position: Int)
}



 open class RecyclerTouchListener(
    context: Context?,
    recycleView: RecyclerView,
    val clicklistener: ClickListener?
) :
    OnItemTouchListener {
    private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
        if (child != null && clicklistener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clicklistener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child))
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {}
    override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}

    init {
        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, object : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
                val child = recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
                if (child != null && clicklistener != null) {
                    clicklistener.onLongClick(child, recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child))
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Implement on recycler view**

```
 rvAds.addOnItemTouchListener( RecyclerTouchListener(mActivity,rvAds,object :ClickListener{
                        override fun onClick(view: View?, position: Int) {


                            val layout = view!!.mainlayoutAds

                            val intent = Intent(mActivity, AdsDetailsActivity::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra(AdsDetailsActivity.TITLE, list[position].massage)
                            intent.putExtra(AdsDetailsActivity.IMAGE, list[position].image)
                            intent.putExtra(AdsDetailsActivity.MESSAGE, list[position].massage)
                            startActivity(intent)


                            layout.setOnClickListener {



                            }
                        }

                        override fun onLongClick(view: View?, position: Int) {

                        }
                    }))
```